# Data analysis using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different DataFrames from a .csv file

Columns in file:

```
Index(['App', 'Category', 'Rating', 'Reviews', 'Size_MBs', 'Installs', 'Type','Price', 'Content_Rating', 'Genres', 'Last_Updated','Android_Ver'],dtype='object')
```

First One:

```
category_installs=df_apps_clean.groupby('Category').agg({'Installs':pd.Series.sum})
category_installs.sort_values('Installs', ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

gives output as:

```
 **Category---------------Installs**

 VIDEO_PLAYERS-------3916897200

 FAMILY-----------------4437554490

 PHOTOGRAPHY--------4649143130

 SOCIAL-----------------5487841475

 PRODUCTIVITY---------5788070180

 TOOLS------------------8099724500

 COMMUNICATION------11039241530

 GAME-------------------13858762717
```

Second one:

```
app_installs = df_apps_clean.groupby('Category').agg({'App':pd.Series.count})
app_installs.sort_values('App', ascending=False)
```

gives output as:

```
**Category--------------App**
            
FAMILY----------------1606

GAME-------------------910

TOOLS------------------719

PRODUCTIVITY----------301

PERSONALIZATION------298

LIFESTYLE---------------297

FINANCE----------------296

MEDICAL----------------292

PHOTOGRAPHY---------263

BUSINESS--------------262

SPORTS----------------260

COMMUNICATION------257
```

but when i'm merging them using pandas merge function like this:

```
cat_merged_df = pd.merge(app_installs, category_installs,on='Category', how='inner')

cat_merged_df.sort_values('Installs', ascending=False)
```

I'm getting output as:

```
**Category----------App_x----------Installs----------App_y**


GAME----------------910----------13858762717--------Ra Ga BaMu.F.O.Brick Breaker BR211:CK 

COMMUNICATION----257---------11039241530---------EJ messengerBest Browser BD social networkingD...

TOOLS----------------719------------8099724500--------ei CalcBM speed testCZ Kompasap,wifi testing,i...

PRODUCTIVITY--------301--------5788070180-----------ER AssistBAMMS for BM SQDL Image ManagerEB Sca...

SOCIAL--------------203------------5487841475---------CB HeroesDN BlogHum Ek Hain 2.02UP EB Bill Pay...
```

Why am I getting 3 columns with App column got split as App_x and App_y?
There is not such data in the file I'm working on.

Comment: Try putting three ` ether side of your code to make a code block like this ```my code``` will make it easier to read.

Comment: Please give an example of how you would like to see the data at the end. Please provide in tabular format.

Comment: I signedup  stackover flow today so I just wrote my problems in text and posted it

Comment: App column in file contains Game names and I have seen in App_y column all game name is added corresponding to each category but which this column got created?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want then maybe this will help.

make df1

```
import pandas as pd

col1 = ['VIDEO_PLAYERS', 'FAMILY', 'PHOTOGRAPHY', 'SOCIAL', 'PRODUCTIVITY', 'TOOLS', 'COMMUNICATION', 'GAME']
col2 = [3916897200, 4437554490, 4649143130, 5487841475, 5788070180, 8099724500, 11039241530, 13858762717]
d = {'Category':col1, 'Installs':col2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)


Category    Installs
0   VIDEO_PLAYERS   3916897200
1   FAMILY  4437554490
2   PHOTOGRAPHY 4649143130
3   SOCIAL  5487841475
4   PRODUCTIVITY    5788070180
5   TOOLS   8099724500
6   COMMUNICATION   11039241530
7   GAME    13858762717
```

make df2

```
col1 = ['FAMILY', 'GAME', 'TOOLS', 'PRODUCTIVITY', 'PERSONALIZATION', 'LIFESTYLE', 'FINANCE', 'MEDICAL', 'PHOTOGRAPHY', 'BUSINESS', 'SPORTS', 'COMMUNICATION']
col2 = [1606, 910, 719, 301, 298, 297, 296, 292, 263, 262, 260, 257]
d = {'Category':col1, 'App':col2}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)

    Category    App
0   FAMILY  1606
1   GAME    910
2   TOOLS   719
3   PRODUCTIVITY    301
4   PERSONALIZATION 298
5   LIFESTYLE   297
6   FINANCE 296
7   MEDICAL 292
8   PHOTOGRAPHY 263
9   BUSINESS    262
10  SPORTS  260
11  COMMUNICATION   257
```

Merge two frames on `Category`

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='Category')


    Category        Installs    App
0   FAMILY          4437554490  1606
1   PHOTOGRAPHY     4649143130  263
2   PRODUCTIVITY    5788070180  301
3   TOOLS           8099724500  719
4   COMMUNICATION   11039241530 257
5   GAME            13858762717 910
```

If this is not what you want please show how you want the output to look and I will update. You can `how=` to change the join type.

Comment: when I'm using pandas .merge function instead of App count from pd.Series.count it has concatenated all app names from .csv files and that is what is being presented as new column  App_y and my query is why is it concatenating App names instead of just giving me App count from App column and why is it creating new column name of App_x instead of just App which I'm getting from app_installs Dataframe hope you understand my doubt. When I've two df with common index Category and columns App and installs then why after merging I'm getting App_x, Installs, App_y. Is it related with pandas merging?

Comment: So merge does that when there is identically named column in both dataframes. It will add the sufix ```_x``` or ```_y```. With the count are ```1606, 263``` etc the count? Or is it that ever time ```1606``` shows you want to count 1?

Comment: Finally resolved, actually I am coding in Google Colaboratory i.e in browser , initially I used pd.Series.sum after that I replaced it with pd.Series.count and each set of code was in different cell so sum of them where not refreshed therefore first I cleared by cache files of chrome then I re-run all cells then I get my desired output

Comment: thanks for you efforts and contribution but it will remain a mystery why two different rows were created. @Cam

Comment: It is hard to diagnose the problem without recreating your situation. It is best when asking a question if you can provide a minimal example showing the full problem end to end.